# Run a compiled java program with its classpath ,from another java program

Tags: java

I am trying to run a compiled java program with its classpath, from another java program. But it doesn't show the result. My code is given below

```
String[] cmd = {"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe","/c","start","javac","D:\\java\\hi\\src\\helo.java"};

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Note: After this, the class file is created but the below code is not working.

```
String[] cmd1 = {"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe","/c","start","java"," -cp D:\\java\\hi\\src"," helo"};

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd1);
```

Comment: What does *not working* mean? Any errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are not getting any exceptions. I am assuming you are getting the class file from correct location.

Since, you are trying to capture the output of the **helo**, you should be capturing the inputstream of the java command you ran in second half.

Try something like: (**Just for the second command**)

```
BufferedReader in = null;
try {  
    String[] cmd1 = {"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe","/c","start","java"," -cp D:\java\hi\src"," helo"};
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd1);  
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  
    String line = null;  
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
        System.out.println(line);  
    }
 } catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
 } finally {
    in.close();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Himanshu Bhardwaj ..This code is working fine and its showing the result in console...Great ...

Answer (score 0):

you need to do like this in order to run dynamically in cmd

Runtime.getRuntime.exec("cmd /c cd/Desktop/folder/ & java  yourprogram");

this assumes you have your class file generated in Desktop/folder/ directory

Things to notice is & - to concat commands and /c to pass the arguments to cmd

Answer (score 0):

read this: http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html 
It's old but as valid 13 years after it was written as it was on the day it went public.

You're almost always better off creating a new classloader on the fly, give that its own environment, and launch in that.